# How to add new text to file names while being input into a text file in unix

Tags: unix, manifest, fastq

Hopefully this is straightforward, but I'm trying to somewhat automate the creation of a manifest file for Qiime. I have a few hundred .fastq files that I want to read into a .txt file with a filepath attached.

For example, the file names are `SRR201691_1.fastq` and I want them to be moved to a .txt file but now contain `/file/path/SRR201691_1.fastq`.  I have the code below that moves the names...

```
ls *1.fastq >> forward-manifest.txt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
printf "/file/path/%s\n" *1.fastq >> forward-manifest.txt
```

should do it.

Comment: I have gotten to the point of an almost useful text output file using `printf "/file/path/%s\n" *1.fastq >> forward-manifest.txt`. However, this inputs quote marks around the fastq file name so that they're listed in the text file as `/file/path/"SRR8302766_1.fastq"` but should instead simply be `/file/path/SRR8302766_1.fastq`